# How to set output path in a Qt project

Tags: qt, path, project, set

After building, Qt Creator puts my output exe in folder "Debug". I want to change the output folder by adding output path to the .pro file. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

In qt you can specify everything on the .pro file.

```
win32 {
  DESTDIR = whatever you want
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! By the way, I want to learn all the keywords used in .pro file, could you do me a favor by recommending some materials?

Comment: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qmake-variable-reference.html. Don't forget to accept this answer if you consider this is the answer you want.